# Java: renameTo keeps failing and returning false

Tags: java

I'm stumped on this one. I know renameTo is tempermental and fails for various reasons but I don't see how its any of the listed reasons.
No file exists with the same name in the same folder nor is any program accessing it.

```
for(int i = 0;i<languageList.size();i++){
            FileUtils extraLangFiles = new FileUtils();
            //File dest = new File(path.getCanonicalPath());
            File temp = new File("./");
            extraLangFiles.copyFileToDirectory(path, temp);
            File tempFile = new File(getFilePath());

            //Checks if file exists before making any edits
            if(tempFile.exists()){


            File tempName = new File(extractLanCode("./temp/" +    tempFile.getName().replace(".xml", "")) + "_" + languageList.get(i)+".xml");
            System.out.println("FileName Change - " + tempName.getName());
            tempFile.renameTo(tempName);

            //check if file is related to itd or project
            if(isITD()==true){
                File dest = new File(itdPath);
                System.out.println("File Name() " + tempFile + ", " + dest);
                extraLangFiles.copyFileToDirectory(tempFile, dest);

                System.out.println("COPY - ITD");
                tempFile.delete();
                languagePath.add(dest + "/" + tempName);
            }else{
                File dest = new File(ProjectPath);
                System.out.println("File Name() " + tempFile + ", " + dest);
                extraLangFiles.copyFileToDirectory(tempFile, dest);
                System.out.println("COPY - Project");
                tempFile.delete();
                languagePath.add(dest + "/" + tempName);
            }                                       
        }               
    }
```

My thought is that it is something to do with copyFileToDirectly, perhaps a stream is being left open from it.

BTW I'm stuck with java 1.6 so can't use any features above that.

Comment: Any errors or exceptions? Tell us more about the files and directory.

Comment: Please list the "reasons" that you have decided don't apply.  (How else would we know what you have considered??)

Comment: "My thought is that it is something to do with copyFileToDirectly, perhaps a stream is being left open from it." => If so, you have to find out. We cannot.

Comment: No errors or exceptions. Its scanning for for xml files in the "./" folder. The newly named files are placed in "./temp" so they can be out of the way and not interfere with renameTo.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry Stephen. Reasons are 1)Don't have write access (impossible considering my program created all the files in the folder) 2)File doesn't exist (files do exist) 3)Something else is using the file (Don't see this as likly given I created the files and only my program uses them, in this case just a copy).

Comment: What OS are you on? Is the source directory navigable and writeable (on some systems, this is vital)? Is the target directory navigable and writeable? What does the program do?

Comment: On some unixes you can't rename across file systems.

Comment: BTW you're not testing return value of `renameTo`.